# react native onPress event not working in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, reactive-programming, hybrid-mobile-app

**My Class Code**

> problem is  onPress function give the following error if i use it in the loop

```
onPress={() => this.onPressButton()}
```

[image]

> nothing happens if i use this line of code

```
onPress={this.onPressButton}
```

> I know this has to do something with binding which i am not getting  kindly help

```
export default class PlayGame extends Component {

  navigate(routName){
    this.props.navigator.push({
     name:  routName
   })
  }

  onPressButton() {
    alert("You tapped the button!");
  }

  render() {
    //var selectedLetter = Globals.URDU_ALPHABETS[Math.floor(Math.random()*Globals.URDU_ALPHABETS.length)];  //will be used when app is MVP
    //add selected array

    var selectedLetter = Globals.URDU_ALPHABETS[1];
    var randLetters =  shuffle(randomLetters(Globals.URDU_ALPHABETS,selectedLetter));
    playSelectedLetter(selectedLetter.name);      
    return (             
     <View style={{flex: 3,backgroundColor: 'silver', flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent:'space-between', alignItems: 'center'}}>                      
     <View style={{width: 400, height: 8, flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}}  /> 
     <View style={{flex: 3,backgroundColor: 'silver', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent:'space-between', alignItems: 'center'}}>

     {Object.keys(randLetters).map(function(key,index) {   

       return <TouchableHighlight key={index} letterName={randLetters[key].name} onPress={() => this.onPressButton()} > 
       <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} key={index}><Text key={index} >{randLetters[key].name}</Text></View> 
       </TouchableHighlight>

     }
     )}
     </View>     
     <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onPressButton}>
     <Text>Button</Text>
     </TouchableHighlight>
     <View style={{width: 0, height: 0, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}}><Text></Text></View>             
     </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing:

```
Object.keys(randLetters).map(function(key,index) {
```

to :

```
Object.keys(randLetters).map((key,index) => {
```

You can bind either in the class constructor or these two ways in render

```
{this.onPressButton.bind(this)}        {() => this.onPressButton()}
```

Comment: Thanks this works for me 
Object.keys(randLetters).map((key,index) => {
but how this works by just changing the syntex !

Comment: Arrow functions change the context of this to the outer scope, so in this case the scope will be the class

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind it to your component context:

```
export default class PlayGame extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onPressButton = this.onPressButton.bind(this)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but this does not solve the problem get the following error
undefined is not an object (evaluating this.onPressButton.bind)

Comment: Have you try to bind it in constructor?

Comment: i am new to react native how can i do that if you can give me an example !

Comment: thanks but above solution work for me , i tried this one too but it did not work for me unfortunately.